# Are there measurements of how much mathematics people remember after high-school?

Tags: secondary-education, reference-request

These days I got curious about something: Are there measurements of how much mathematics people remember after high-school?

Comment: This question seems pretty vague and general, and could benefit from some effort at research by the OP. Some people go to college and take more math. Some people become supermarket clerks. Some of the random stuff crammed into high school math classes is simply not useful, and I don't remember it myself. Some people remember algorithms but don't understand what they're doing.

Comment: @user615 While your anecdote is interesting, it is quite likely that your friend remembered the math she learned earlier than the math she learned later.  I would expect that most people would remember the basic algebra studied in 9th grade, but not the more advanced math studied later.

Comment: [An interesting paper on the subject](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1022429504802), albeit from 2002. Perhaps some reference diving would lead to more recent papers on this?